# Unknown condition satisfaction in pthread cond timedwait

Tags: c, linux, g++, pthreads

There's something going on in my code that I didn't intend.

I've got a program with several threads. One thread reads a rfid chip and saves the rfid code string into a global struct variable. There are also some other threads that are opened when a client, which is supposed to get the string, connects to the program on a certain socket. They are on a timed waiting (pthread_cond_timedwait) for the reading thread to broadcast a pthread condition variable (thread->done) that signals that a rfid chip was read and there is a new string to be sent to the clients. Now to the problem: the pthread_cond_timedwait in the sending thread shall only be satisfied when a new string is ready to be sent, but it also triggers when a new client thread is opened. The client threads start with the function below. I hope I explained my problem clearly and anyone can help me with the problem.

code of the sending function:

```
void* send_data(void* arg)
{
  int client_id;
  int status_timeout;

  struct timespec timeout;
  struct Thread_parameter *thread = (struct Thread_parameter*)arg;

  pthread_condattr_t attr;
  pthread_condattr_init(&attr);
  pthread_condattr_setclock(&attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
  pthread_cond_init(&thread->done, &attr);

  // read the client id from struct
  pthread_mutex_lock(&thread->mutex);
  client_id = thread->t_client_id;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread->mutex);

  while (1)
  {
    // wait for string
    while (1)
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&thread->mutex);
      status_timeout = ETIMEDOUT;

      while (1)
      {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timeout);
        timeout.tv_sec += 1;

        status_timeout = pthread_cond_timedwait(&thread->done, &thread->mutex, &timeout);

        // Timeout
        if (status_timeout == ETIMEDOUT)
        {
          if (is_connected(client_id))
            continue;
          else
          {
            log_output("Lost connection to client '%i'", client_id);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread->mutex); 
            pthread_exit(NULL);
          }
        }
        else if (status_timeout == 0)
        {
          // condition satisfied
          break;
        }
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread->mutex);  
      break;
    }

    // send the string to the client when the condition is satisfied
    while (1)
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&thread->mutex);
      if (send(client_id, thread->t_chip_id, CHIP_ID_LENGTH, MSG_NOSIGNAL) >= 0)
      {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread->mutex);
        log_output("Successfully sent data to client '%i'", client_id);
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread->mutex);
        // sending not successful, check if client is still connected
        if (is_connected(client_id))
          continue;
        else
        {
          close(client_id);
          log_output("Lost connection to client '%i'", client_id);
          pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `man pthread_cond_wait: A condition (short for ``condition variable'') is a synchronization  device that  allows  threads  to  suspend  execution and relinquish the processors until some predicate on shared data is satisfied.` A condition variable is not a semaphore. You need a predicate to test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I heard about that but didn't know how to implement it..Can you give me a tip how to put it in my code?

Comment: You probably want something like `while (!is_ready_to_send) pthread_cond_timedwait()`, where the predicate `is_read_to_send` is shared between the threads. Since the predicate is non-readonly and shared, it must be protected by appropriate synchronization (mutex), or must be an atomic type. Since using a condition-variable requires a mutex, you can simply protect every access to the predicate with the same mutex that protects the condition-variable.